# A discontinuity of a zero homogenous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a linear and positively homogenous function of degree zero. If $f$ vanishes on a plane, does this imply that $f$ is zero everywhere or it has a discontinuity at a direction parallel to that plane?

Comment: Could you define a zero homogeneous function for us? My guess is that a zero homogeneous function is one that satisfies $$f(\lambda \mathbf{x}) = f(\mathbf{x})$$ for all $\mathbf x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: Also, when you say "plane", I believe you're referring to an $(n-1)$ dimensional manifold embedded in $\mathbb R^n$, right?

Comment: Regarding the homogeneity, yes as you write and we can add that $\lambda>0$. By a plane, I mean there are two independent vectors or elements $x,y$ in $R^n$ such that $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=0$ also $f$ vanishes on all combinations of $x$ and $y$ (by the way $f$ is linear)

Comment: I think you should mention in your post that $f$ is linear. This is not clear. Also, why do you choose $\lambda > 0$? Did you mean $\lambda \ne 0$ instead?

Comment: I will add the linearity property. I added $\lambda>0$ because $f$ in fact is positively homogenous.

Comment: Why not add that $f$ is positively homogeneous in your post?

Comment: Sorry, I will add it also.

Comment: If $f$ is positively homogeneous of degree $0$, and linear, it is the null function: $\forall \lambda > 0, f(\lambda x) = \lambda f(x) = f(x)$, so $f(x) = 0$. Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: You are right. What about if it is non linear and vanishes on a plane generated by two directions?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not see you had answered my comment (please put @<destinee> when you reply to someone who is not the OP).

If $f$ is a positively homogeneous function of degree zero, non necessarily linear, that is null on a $k$-dimension plane, $k < n$:

- If this is a vector plane (i.e. it includes zero), $f$ is null on that plane and we cannot conclude it is null elsewhere.
- If it is an affine plane that does not include zero, f is null on the $k+1$-dimension vector space generated by this plane and zero.

If $f$ is non-null elsewhere, as $\forall \lambda > 0, \forall x, f(\lambda x) = f(x)$, with $\lambda \to 0$ we see there is a discontinuity on $0$. Actually an homogeneous function of degree $0$ has a discontinuity on $0$ as soon as it is not fully constant on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.